# knockout - need to update a view with an object of an array

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of objects, in which each of the objects defines elements of a particular modal I want to display. 
so it is like.

```
var data = [{view1:"hello", view2:"world"}];

var viewModel = {
     currentView: ko.observable({})   // are objects observable?
};
```

Then when I load the modal, I get the object out of the array.

```
var getDataForView = function (id) {
        var result = data.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.Id == id;
        });
        return result;
    };
```

Then load that object as the current view.

```
var singleViewData = getDataForView(id);
viewModel.currentView(singleViewData);
```

The object does not seem to be updating? When I call different views. What am I doing wrong here, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`getDataForView` returns an array. Also, the test data you provided does not contain any objects with an `Id` property.

If you fix these issues, everything works as expected:

```js
var data = [{
  view1: "hello",
  Id: 0
}, {
  view2: "world",
  Id: 1
}];

var viewModel = {
  currentView: ko.observable({}) // are objects observable?
};

var getDataForView = function(id) {
  var result = data.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.Id == id;
  });
  return result;
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

var singleViewData = getDataForView(0)[0];
viewModel.currentView(singleViewData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: currentView">
  <pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify($data, null, 2)">

</pre>

</div>
```

Instead of `.filter()[0]` you could also use `Array.prototype.find` if your browser support allows it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that was helpful, I was able to get the data to display. Their is still a part that is not working for me though, I will need to write a separate post.

Comment: Glad to hear you (mostly) figured it out. I tried to propose a "fix" that stays as close to your initial code as possible. You might want to check out the other answers as well for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a computed

```
var data = [{view1:"hello", view2:"world"}];

var viewModel = {
    views      : ko.observable( data ),
    currentId : ko.observable('view1')
};
viewModel.currentView = ko.computed( function(){
    var cid = viewModel.currentId();
    var views = viewModel.views();
    if( views.hasOwnProperty( cid ) ){
       return views[cid];
    } else {
       return "";
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is about WHY your views are not updating the values inside them. The reason for this is because while `currentView` is observable, the data that is contained inside it is **NOT** observable. If you want to update the values 'hello' and 'world' then they will have to **also** be observable. I'm sure your example is somewhat contrived and that you do have id's in your data - but the answer to your question is this:

- If you want a value to be updated then it needs to be an observable or it will not be updated. This means the individual properties and not just the object they belong to.

```js
var data = [{ id: 123, view: ko.observable("hello") },
            { id: 456, view: ko.observable("world") }];

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.currentView = ko.observable() // anything can be observable
};

 var getDataForView = function(id) {
    var result = data.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.id == id;
    });
    if (result.length === 0) 
      return; 
    return result[0].view();
  };

var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.currentView(getDataForView(456));
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: currentView"/>
<br/>
<br/>
Current view: <b data-bind="text: currentView"></b>
```